# Cannot resolve the collation conflict

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, reporting-services

I am getting the following error message.

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I only get it when I place this code below in my WHERE clause.

```
WHERE Region IN (SELECT Token FROM dbo.getParmsFromString(@Region))
```

Now @Region contains all the values from my multi-select fields from SSRS.

Below is the code for the function that is used.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getParmsFromString]
    (@String VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Parms TABLE
(
    Token VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(',', @String) != 0
    BEGIN
        ;WITH cte0(Token, List) AS
              (
                SELECT   SUBSTRING(@String, 1, CHARINDEX(',',@String,1) - 1)
                        ,SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX(',',@String,1) + 1, LEN(@String)) + ','

                UNION ALL

                SELECT     SUBSTRING(List,1,ISNULL(CHARINDEX(',',List,1) - 1,1))
                        ,SUBSTRING(List,CHARINDEX(',',List,1) + 1, LEN(List))
                FROM cte0
                WHERE LEN(cte0.List) > 0
              )

            INSERT INTO @Parms (Token)
            SELECT Token
            FROM cte0
            OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
        RETURN;
    END

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @Parms
            SELECT @String
        RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
 RETURNS @Parms TABLE 
( 
    Token VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
```

with

```
try changing RETURNS @Parms TABLE 
( 
    Token VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
)
```

and

```
WHERE Region IN (SELECT Token FROM dbo.getParmsFromString(@Region))
```

with

```
WHERE Region COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  IN (SELECT Token FROM dbo.getParmsFromString(@Region))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of error occurs when you try to compare the the data of different regions or when you compare data using a specific encryption with other data using a different encryption.
The most probable reason is that their tempdb is using the collation **"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"** while the database is using **"Latin1_General_CI_AS"**.  As a result, temp objects are created under the collation **"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"** and then fail to compare with database objects of the database which are using the collation **"Latin1_General_CI_AS"**.

The easiest fix and also the one which would recommended would be to run the database on a server which was installed using collation **"Latin1_General_CI_AS"**.

FYI. SQL collations(**"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"**) are present in sql server for backward compatibility.  When dealing with international data or databases using unicode and non unicode data, it is recommended to use windows collations (**"Latin1_General_CI_AS"**).

You can change your database collation by:

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE "Your database"
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;

SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases;
```

and if needed you can also change the collation of "master" database i.e. rebuilding the database, for this go through to these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003(v=sql.100).aspx

http://sqlbuzz.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-rebuild-master-database-aka-rebuilding-sql-server-2008r2/

but make sure you backup all your database before doing this.