# SQL Server: Cannot resolve the collation conflict, despite conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I still get the error code

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

despite the fact that I'm using conversion as per [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and) two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639163/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict). Here is my code:

```
-- ...
from #TmpResult a
left join #GroupMemberTable b
on (a.DBO_Owner_Login COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) = (b.login_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

I have converted them both to:  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Thank you

***UPDATE:*** 
Here is the full excerpt:

```
create table #TmpTableSec3 (database_name varchar(100), Database_Owner varchar(200), DBO_Owner_Login varchar(200), type varchar (100), privilege varchar(100), group_name varchar(500))
insert into #TmpTableSec3
select a.database_name, a.principal, a.DBO_Owner_Login, b.type, b.privilege, b.group_name
from #TmpResult a
left join #GroupMemberTable b
on (a.DBO_Owner_Login COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) = (b.login_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
    --a.DBO_Owner_Login = b.login_name
    --fieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = otherfieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
where b.group_name is not null --and b.privilege = 'admin'
order by a.database_name
```

Then that table is populated by:

```
insert into #TmpResult
select a.database_name, a.Owner, b.DBO_Owner_Login from #TmpTableSec1 a
join #TmpTableSec2 b
on a.database_name = b.database_name


  set @cmd = 'select name,  suser_sname(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name = '''+@name+''''
  --select @cmd
  insert #TmpTableSec1 exec (@cmd)
  --select @dbowner = (select suser_sname(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name = @name)
  set @cmd = 'use '+ @name +'
  select db_name(), name, suser_sname(sid)
  from sys.database_principals where name = ''dbo'''
  --select ''@DBO'' = (select suser_sname(sid) from sys.database_principals where name = ''dbo'') '
  INSERT #TmpTableSec2 exec (@cmd)
```

Comment: the problem might be in the `.....` part of your code

Comment: Please post the whole code you are trying to execute

Comment: @NickyvV I posted more, but I think the issue is only related to that one line

Comment: You are inserting data to a table, the error is most likely that the collation definition for some column is different than the one you are inserting. If the problem was with `a.DBO_Owner_Login`, you might want to use `a.DBO_Owner_Login COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in the `SELECT` too (or the appropriate collation)

Comment: By chance is one of the fields  stored as text in the original tables?

Comment: have you tried to avoid collation?

Comment: When you double click on the error message in SSMS, does it highlight that line of code?

Comment: @Michaelbuller , yes of course, that's the line you see at the top of the question. I posted that only first, but everyone asked for the *whole* code

Comment: @mcNets how would i **avoid** collation???

Comment: you're using temp tables, why are not using the same collation in the column definition?  and using collation in both sides of comparison, you're forcing collation in both columns, force the collation in one column only.

Comment: have you tried using a view that returns all 'char' fields in one specific collation, instead of using tables directly?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table #test
drop table #test2

create table #test
(id int, name varchar(100) collate Latin1_General_CI_AI
CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)

create table #test2
(id int, name varchar(100) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CONSTRAINT [PK_test2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)

insert into #test values (1, 'premonition')
insert into #test values (2, 'premònition')
insert into #test values (3, 'lowmotion')

insert into #test2 values (1, 'premonition')
insert into #test2 values (2, 'premònition')
insert into #test2 values (3, 'lowmotion')

select * 
from #test 
inner join #test2 
    on #test.name = #test2.name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

`collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` forces the comparison to this collate, I'm using the same collation defined in #test2.name

Maybe this 'Collation precedence' article can help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx